# Dynamically pull API data based on form field value in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, api

I'm trying to create a form where users can search for a medical facility in a location using Django. The search results come from an API that displays countries, regions, cities, and the medical facilities within those locations. So far I have created the functions that pull in ALL of the data:

```
import requests


MAIN_URL = 'https://www.sample.com'
API_KEY = 123456789


def get_countries():
    response = requests.get('{}/GetCountryList?apikey={}'.format(MAIN_URL, API_KEY))
    json_response = response.json()
    countries = json_response['GetCountryListResult']
    return countries


def get_regions(country):
    response = requests.get('{}/GetRegionList?countrycode={}&apikey={}'.format(MAIN_URL, country, API_KEY))
    json_response = response.json()
    regions = json_response['GetRegionListResult']
    return regions


def get_cities(country, region):
    response = requests.get('{}/GetCityList?countrycode={}&regioncode={}&apikey={}'.format(MAIN_URL, country, region, API_KEY))
    json_response = response.json()
    cities = json_response['GetCityListResult']
    return cities


def get_facilities(country, region, city):
    response = requests.get('{}/SearchByCity?city={}&regioncode={}&countrycode={}&apikey={}'.format(MAIN_URL, city, region, country, API_KEY))
    json_response = response.json()
    facilities = json_response['GetFacilitiesByCityResult']
    return facilities
```

I have also created the view and passed these items through in context:

```
class MedicalFacilitiesPage(Page, TranslatablePageMixin):

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(MedicalFacilitiesPage, self).get_context(request)
        context['countries'] = get_countries()
        context['regions'] = get_regions(country)
        context['cities'] = get_cities(country, region)
        context['facilities'] = get_facilities(country, region, city)

        return context
```

The data is showing up in the select boxes when I do something like this:

```
<select class="form-control searchOption" id="Country" name="Country">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {% for country in countries %}
    <option value="{{ country.CountryCode }}">{{ country.CountryName }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

However, I need to pull only the results that are relevant to the previous select box's value. So for example, someone selects 'Canada' in the first select box, I need to display all of the Regions that belong in Canada ONLY in the Region select box. And then once they select a region, I need to display ONLY the cities that belong in that Region in the City select box. I would need to determine the value of the select box and pass it back to the functions pulling that info from the API, but I'm not sure how I would do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look on this blogpost https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: and ask yourself few questsion: does it have to go through backend? why not make this requests straight from javascript to the external service (eventually using django only for proxy for injecting api key if it matters)?